# Trying to associate an entity to another results in an insert

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am new to Doctrine 2 and I am trying to Create a new `Transaction` then try to see if that `Transaction` belong to any `pre-existing Category`. If it does then associate this `Transaction` to the given `Category`

When I run the code below at the highlighted point it should associate the `Transaction` to a `Category`. But I get the following `Error` which then tells me that the code is trying to add a new `Category`... but what I need it to do is to add a new reference in the table `transactions_category` (see the Picture below to see this table schema) and NOT a new Category... as that one already exists....

Its a `ManyToMany` association

How can I associate the two entities properly?

[image]

**The Error:**

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO category (name) VALUES (?)' with params ["Gyms"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Gyms' for key 'name'
```

**The Code**

```
   // Get all Categories
$categoryList = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Bnk\Entity\Category')->findAll();

foreach ( $CSVData as $transactionRaw )
{
    $transaction = new \Bnk\Entity\Transaction();
    $transaction->setDescription( $transactionRaw[ "description" ] );
    $transaction->setValue( $transactionRaw[ "value" ] );
    $transaction->setDate( $transactionRaw[ "date" ] );
    $transaction->setAccountnumber( $transactionRaw[ "accountNumber" ] );
    $transaction->setAccountname( $transactionRaw[ "accountName" ] );

    $this->getEntityManager()->persist( $transaction );

    // Check if there are categories
    if(!empty($categoryList))
    {
        // Loop through the categories
        /** @var \Bnk\Entity\Category $category */
        foreach( $categoryList as $category )
        {
            if( !$regexEntities = $category->getCategoryregex() )

                // Loop through the regex of a given category
                /** @var \Bnk\Entity\CategoryRegex $regex */
                foreach( $regexEntities as $regex )
                {
                    if(strpos($transactionRaw["description"],$regex->getName()) !== false)
                    {

                        // I am trying to associate the Transaction to this Category
                        // Instead this is adding the Category as if it was a new one
                        $transaction->addCategory($category);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

   $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
   $this->getEntityManager()->clear();
}
```

Comment: can you please post your schema definitions, especially for the table/entity that has the `name` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to persist your `transaction` and flush before adding `category` :

```
$this->getEntityManager()->persist( $transaction );
$this->getEntityManager()->flush();

//add category
$transaction->addCategory($category);
$this->getEntityManager()->persist( $transaction );
$this->getEntityManager()->flush();
```